How to add continuous speech/talk - .NET MAUI
I have the below .Net MAUI code that works great.
I want to add continuous speech, I mean when I speak, the recorder must not stop until I press stop button.
In the below code, when I stop speaking, or I pause for like 2-3 sec, it stops itself, so I don't want it to behave like that.
I want it to continue recording even if i pause my speech for 2-3 sec.
public class SpeechToTextImplementation : ISpeechToText
{
    public event EventHandler<SpeechToTextRecognitionResultUpdatedEventArgs> RecognitionResultUpdated = null!;
    public event EventHandler<SpeechToTextRecognitionResultCompletedEventArgs> RecognitionResultCompleted = null!;
    public event EventHandler<SpeechToTextStateChangedEventArgs> StateChanged = null!;

    public SpeechToTextState CurrentState { get; private set; } = SpeechToTextState.Idle;

    public async Task<SpeechToTextResult> ListenAsync(CultureInfo culture, IProgress<string>? recognitionResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);
        string finalText = "Recognized text from ListenAsync.";
        recognitionResult?.Report(finalText);
        return new SpeechToTextResult(finalText, null);
    }

    public async Task StartListenAsync(CultureInfo culture, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        CurrentState = SpeechToTextState.Listening;
        StateChanged?.Invoke(this, new SpeechToTextStateChangedEventArgs(CurrentState));

        
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            RecognitionResultUpdated?.Invoke(this, new SpeechToTextRecognitionResultUpdatedEventArgs(new SpeechToTextRecognitionResult("Simulated intermediate result.")));
            return true; 
        });
    }

    public async Task StopListenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        await Task.Delay(500, cancellationToken);
        CurrentState = SpeechToTextState.Stopped;
        StateChanged?.Invoke(this, new SpeechToTextStateChangedEventArgs(CurrentState));

        
        RecognitionResultCompleted?.Invoke(this, new SpeechToTextRecognitionResultCompletedEventArgs(new SpeechToTextRecognitionResult("Simulated final result.")));
    }

    public async Task<bool> RequestPermissions(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        await Task.Delay(500, cancellationToken);
        return true;
    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
}


You can try this: MauiSpeechToTextSample.
